# Sum rasters without clipping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, clip, raster-calculator

I'm using Raster Calculator in ArcMap.

Is there a way to make operations between rasters in a way that the output raster is not clipped with the same extent of the smaller raster considered in the calculation?

Comment: Try cell statistics

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to indicate whether you are using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro. Either way, you should check out the Environments tab, and especially the Processing Extent option.